# Tooltips in highcharts map

Tags: highcharts, maps, tooltip

How to set tooltip in highcharts map not hidden or moved after showing first time, if click again hide tooltip and so.

Comment: Hi @andlib, Could you add more details? Do you want to show a tooltip on hover at first time and each subsequent one?

Comment: Dear @ppotaczek, I want the ToolTip to appear when I click on the touchscreen devices the ToolTip will remain on and not disappear until I click again.

Comment: but this is the exact way how the tooltip works with touchscreen devices. You can test this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z8mp12k5/show on some device with touchscreen.